# JSX is not compiling with Jasmine/PhantomJS test

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, jasmine, phantomjs, webpack

I cannot write a test and include a rendering of a component with my react/jasmine/phantomjs test.

I try the following:

```
beforeEach(function(){

        var component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
        <JsonTab results = [1,2,3]/>
);
```

and I get the error: Unexpected token <

I am using JSX-loader with webpack so I am not sure why this component cannot be compiled. Any ideas? I am new to react testing.

Comment: Are you sure phantom is getting it's code from webpack?

Comment: Your file is definitely not being converted from .jsx to .js as you intend it to.

Comment: How are you running your Jasmine tests? Karma?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are running your Jasmine tests, but in general if you want JSX in your tests you will need a compiler. Here is one sample of a compiler to transform your code into something that any runner will understand:

```
//based on https://github.com/danvk/mocha-react
var fs = require('fs');
var babel = require('babel-core');
var origJs = require.extensions['.js'];

// A module that exports a single, stubbed-out React Component.
var reactStub = 'module.exports = require("react").createClass({render:function(){return null;}});';

// Should this file be stubbed out for testing?
function shouldStub(filename) {
  if (!global.reactModulesToStub) {
    return false;
  }

  // Check if the file name ends with any stub path.
  var stubs = global.reactModulesToStub;
  for (var i = 0; i < stubs.length; i++) {
    if (filename.substr(-stubs[i].length) == stubs[i]) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

// Transform a file via JSX/Harmony or stubbing.
function transform(filename) {
  if (shouldStub(filename)) {
    return reactStub;
  } else {
    var content = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
    return babel.transform(content).code;
  }
}

// Install the compiler.
require.extensions['.js'] = function(module, filename) {
  // optimization: code in a distribution should never go through JSX compiler.
  if (filename.indexOf('node_modules/') >= 0) {
    return (origJs || require.extensions['.js'])(module, filename);
  }

  return module._compile(transform(filename), filename);
};

module.exports = {
  transform: transform,
  shouldStub: shouldStub
};
```